# Script manager popup doesn't appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I have an ASP.NET page. I want to throw a pop up upon clicking a certain button on the page. The syntax I used is this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Invalid Address!!');", true);
```

The popup did not appear.

However, when trying the same syntax on a different page in the same project, it worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you're just trying this for testing purposes. But in my experience, a JavaScript `alert` dialog is exceedingly ugly and should be avoided in favor of [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx), [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), [Bootstrap Modal or Dialog](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) etc.

Comment: you are right, its realy ugly, but I need only simple error massegeBox  and its enough for this. and I cant understand why didnt it work on this page.

Comment: So are you throwing the alert after certain validation fails at the code behind? Or if it's a straight away alert to popup when you click the button then you can write 'onclick' event for the button at the markup itself.

Comment: yes, I am throwing the alert after certain validation fails at the code behind inside a **DeleteMethod of listView**, that is in an **updatePanel** (maybe its the reason of the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below line from

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Invalid Address!!');", true);
```

to

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Invalid Address!!');", true);
```

If for whatever reason the above code doesn't work, try the below if it works

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "alert",
                            "Javascript:displayAlert('Invalid Address!!');", true);
```

and your JS function

```
function displayAlert(msg) {
   alert(msg);
   return false;
}
```