# Show error message on webpage if there trying to add duplicate value into database?

Tags: asp.net

I have the interface to create a new customer with both customer code and customer name which will be insert into the Customer table. The code could not be duplicate in the table. What I want to do is to show a error message on the webpage if there is duplicate code being typed into the Customer code area and submit. How could i do this? Following is my code, thanks!

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.InsertCustomer";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCode", txtCustomerCode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", txtRemark.Text);

        try
        { 
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string message = "New Customer Created!";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());                       
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? What doesn't it do, or what does it do wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Set an output parameter in our stored procedure that check to see if code is already exists then set your error message to that output parameter. the in your code behind get the value of the output parameter and check if its null or empty, if not then there was an error

Comment: if there is duplicate customer code entered, I want the error message to show on the webpage such as "Customer Code Already Exist!"

Comment: are you expecting the dbo.InsertCustomer to throw an exception when inserting duplicate customer which will be trapped into the catch block? so you want error message to be triggered from the catch block?

Comment: @dansasu11 Thanks. but what control should i use to show that error message on the screen?

Comment: @ChitownCoding, a label, a literal, a modal popup, is up to you as long as it has runat="server" and you can access from code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a label to the message. Something like.

```
if(ex.Message.ToString().Contains("Duplicate"))  
    this.lblMessage.Text = "Code "+txtCustomerCode.Text+" is already taken."
else
    this.lblMessage.Text = msg;
```

Not sure of the exact text to look for.  You would also not rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the route you're taking using the `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` you can put this in the catch block if you have written your procedure to cause an exception when duplicate occurs

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Customer code already exists !!');", true);
```

Refer my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315618/script-manager-popup-doesnt-appear/24316501#24316501) for the similar problem like yours